# Independent algorithm implementation irrespective of what it is targeting

Tags: algorithm, api, implementation, methodology

I am wondering if there is any architecture or guidelines already existing for defining algorithms and problems in way then can addressed N->N on demand. I have developed many algorithms (like brute Force, specialized to some paper) for solving problems. I found that I was doing repetitive work since algorithm and problem are interweaved in implementation to define  solution. May be my approach is not best in implementation but I am getting what I wanted.

I am looking for architecture reference or guidelines for general basis algorithm(s) implementation and defining problems separate. So that an already implemented algorithm can be used to solve new problem. This way I can write algorithms like API, and use them when ever a problem need to be solved.

Any references would be great. I don't bother about programming platform since I can adapt to it in no time.

Comment: For some algorithms it is easy, e.g. sorting. All you need is a compare function for the elements and you can sort anything. Can you give another example? One you have trouble to generalize?